# External lists: Field GUIDs always empty?

Tags: 2010, external-list, spfield, splist

I want to turn an external list into a DataTable using the ID/GUID values of external list's Fields as the DataTable column names; however, I've noticed for the external list I'm using, all of the GUIDs are empty (all zeros).  Are field GUIDs on any external list always empty?